Adding time with strtotime give incorrect results when going past midnight
I recently noticed that if I run the following command:
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("2024-11-26 23:30:00 +3600 seconds"));

The result is 2024-11-27 12:30:00 which is incorrect. The expected result is 2024-11-27 00:30:00
I don't know if this is something that broke with a recent update or if this has always been broken. My php version is 8.2.26.
Note, when I do:
$newDate = new DateTime("2024-11-26 23:30:00");
$newDate->modify("+3600 seconds");
echo $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

I get the correct date of 2024-11-27 00:30:00.

Notice the different output formats you've used in each example...tempted to just vote this closed as a typo

I think the problem is format string that you used in date() function... Specifically, h:i:s (lowercase h) is for 12-hour format and not the 24-hour format.

H (uppercase) represents the hour in 24-hour format.
h (lowercase) represents the hour in 12-hour format.

